# Homeomorphism between half sphere and whole sphere

Tags: general-topology

Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on the sphere $$S^2=\left\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3 \mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \right\}$$ given by $$(x,y,z)\sim (-x,-y,z).$$ Prove that $S^2/{\sim}$ with quotient topology is homeomorphic to $S^2$.

My plan is to construct a quotient map from $S^2$ to itself which is constant for the equivalent class in $S^2$, then the induced map from $S^2/{\sim}$ to $S^2$ is homeomorphism. But I don't know how to construct it. Or is there some other approach?

Comment: It dont seems that half sphere and a whole sphere are homeomorphic. Are you sure?

Comment: Do you know how to show that $S^1/x\sim-x\cong S^1$?

Comment: @Stahl with pictures? :)

Comment: The closed half-sphere (cut by the z-axis) certainly contains an element in every equivalence class, but that doesn't mean "half-sphere" is an accurate description of the quotient space. Indeed, points on diameter of this half sphere are equivalent to their antipodes, except the north and south pole. The homeomorphism $S^2\!/\!\sim\,\to S^2$ reminds me of a particularly gruesome poster, "The Gentleman's Guide to Amputation."

Comment: @arctictern I could not decide between thanking you and hating you.

Comment: The symbol $\sim$, being normally used as a binary relation symbol, usually has a certain amount of space to its left and right, thus: $a\sim b.$ But that spacing ceases to be appropriate in  $S/\sim.$ The way to get rid of it is by coding it as S/{\sim}, so that nothing is to its left or right, thus: $S/{\sim}.$ I edited the question accordingly. (Also, notice my use of \mathbb and \mid in my edit to the question.) $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Using $\theta$ for longitude and $\phi$ for latitude, consider the map 
$$
(\theta, \phi) \mapsto (2\theta \bmod 2\pi, \phi)
$$
and notice that $(\theta, \phi)$ and $(\theta + \pi, \phi)$ (i.e., $(x, y, z)$ and $(-x, -y, z)$) map to the same place. This provides a 1-1 map from $S^2$ to the quotient you described. You still need to prove it's a homeomorphism, but in one direction that's very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha=\text{longitude}\in \mathbb R/(2\pi)$ and $\beta=\text{latitude with 0 at the north pole and $\pi$ at the south pole}.$

Consider this mapping:
$$
\Big( (\sin\beta) \big(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha\big), \cos\beta \Big) \mapsto \Big( (\sin\beta)\big(\cos(2\alpha),\sin(2\alpha)\big), \cos\beta \Big)
$$
A homeomorphism.

(This was inspired by the fact that $e^{i\theta} \mapsto e^{2i\theta}$ is a homeomorphism from the circle $|z|=1$ modulo the identification of $z$ with $-z$, to the circle $|z|=1$.)